# My filter Function in Excel is throwing a 'Value not Available' NA error even though the values exist

Tags: excel, excel-formula

The formula is:

```
=FILTER(Table1[PREMIUM_ACCOUNT_ID],(Table1[GRADE]=8),"--")
```

I want to filter out the premium IDs for Eighth Grade. In the Table, the Grade column is of lookup values whereas the Premium IDs are alphanumeric Values. There are no leading spaces type of error because when I separately do `=countif( Table1[GRADE], 8)` I get a result.

When I used the formula `(TRIM(Table1[ATTENDED_FLAG])="TRUE")` in the [include] argument where the ATTENDED_FLAG column is of non lookup values, it worked fine.

Comment: Perhaps the entries in the GRADE column are not numeric, but numbers stored as text? In which case you'd need `(Table1[GRADE]="8")`. `COUNTIF` is more 'lenient' in terms of referenced datatypes.

Comment: I've tried that as well actually. Doesn't seem to work. I've even tried using VALUE() around the range, but to no use.

Comment: Perhaps you should check each of the entries in the GRADE column as to whether it's numeric or not, using the `ISNUMBER` function. Perhaps you have a mix of numerics and numbers stored as text.

Comment: Instead of (Table1[GRADE]="8"), I actually used ISNUMBER(Table1[GRADE]), and I got an Output. So that wasn't an issue as well.

Comment: But of course that will give an output, that's not in question. But you have to now analyse the results of that output to see for which entries it returns TRUE and for which it returns FALSE.

Comment: Got it, there was an NA in between that I seemed to miss. Thanks!